# Two-way imputation: A Bayesian method for estimating missing scores in tests and questionnaires, and an accurate approximation

Tags: bayesian, data-imputation

I read the article "Two-way imputation: A Bayesian method for estimating missing
scores in tests and questionnaires, and an accurate approximation" by Van Ginkel et al. (available [here](http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/ginkel2006.pdf)) about a Bayesian two-way imputation method for estimating missing scores in tests and questionnaires.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to implement this? Is there a package or function (in e.g. R or SPSS) available that can deal with this method?

Comment: this and some other question of yours are mainly about programming, so they don't quite fit here. You might want to have a look at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) which is meant to provide programming support.

Comment: Use WinBugs....

Comment: On Stackoverflow it was put on hold... because of being off topic.

Comment: This is a difficult situation for us: because the question clearly is about `R` and also because it is unlikely any *general*, `R`-independent answer would be forthcoming (or any more helpful than the paper itself), it is off topic here. But because writing such code would be so heavily specialized, apparently the SO community felt it was off topic there. *If* this question did not stipulate that `R` had to be the programming environment, and instead asked for *any* solution, I believe this question would indeed be on topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed my question a bit. I hope it's proper now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant...

This specific method of two-way imputation is available as SPSS syntax created by the authors of the article. The syntax and brief manual could be found here: http://socialsciences.leiden.edu/educationandchildstudies/childandfamilystudies/organisation/staffcfs/van-ginkel.html (scroll to the very bottom of the page)